# Replace double consecutive single quotation mark

Tags: c#, string, replace, special-characters, single-quotes

I'm trying to replace double consecutive single quotation marks to null, like this:

```
//my string is " replace '' to null "
str.Replace("''", "null");
//now my string is " replace null to null "
```

But this is happening:

```
//my string is " replace '' to null "
str.Replace("''", "null");
//sadly my string still is " replace '' to null "
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 2):

`string.Replace` does not modify input `string` instead - it returns a new one instead. Reassign it back to your variable to see the change.

```
str = str.Replace("''", "null");
```